# Why is this declared combobox throwing an invocation exception?

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I've got a combobox set in the main window in xaml, but when I try to get the index I get a null reference in code. Why?

```
ComboBox Name="cmbo_addvar_datatype" Margin="4,0,1,0" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  ToolTip="Select a datatype for the variable being added." SelectionChanged="test_addedVar">
                            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" ToolTip="True/Flase value.">Boolean</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="">Little</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>Big</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Text value">String</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Value with a decimal point">Decimal</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="List of strings.">String list</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Array of type little">Array(little)</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="Array of type big">Array(big)</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
```

mainwindow.xaml.vb

```
Dim dataType As String = cmbo_addvar_datatype.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: What version are you using? Works find for me in 2012. (Assuming you meant <ComboBox .....)

Comment: Sorry, I did mean combobox... That's the thing. I have the same type of code on another combobox and it works 100%. I'm wondering if Visual Studio didn't fail to link something in another file. Maybe mainwindow.g.vb.. I tried deleting the combobox and making a new one with a new name, but nothing...

Comment: Here's the mentions in that file..  #ExternalSource("..\..\MainWindow.xaml",112)
    <System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")>  _
    Friend WithEvents cmbo_addvar_datatype As System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
    
    #End ExternalSource

Comment: #ExternalSource("..\..\MainWindow.xaml",200)
    <System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")>  _
    Friend WithEvents cmbo_addImageType As System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
    
    #End ExternalSource

Comment: If (connectionId = 24) Then
            Me.cmbo_addvar_datatype = CType(target,System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)
            
            #ExternalSource("..\..\MainWindow.xaml",112)
            AddHandler Me.cmbo_addvar_datatype.SelectionChanged, New System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(AddressOf Me.test_addvar)
            
            #End ExternalSource
            Return

        End If